# D3.js with hyperlinks in tooltips.

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I've followed the tool tip example [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html#_html_div_tooltips) from the Data Visualizations book and hoped to create a d3.js graph that utilises hyperlinked content in its tooltips.

I was able to add hyperlinks to [@FernOfTheAndes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2826181/fernoftheandes) [JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/5PENv/) of this visualisation. My hyperlinked version is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisGuest/x0mg4v1q/).

But my more [*real world example*](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisGuest/9u9a30y4/) of a Scatterplot with hyperlinked Tooltips is not working. It would seem that the hrefs are being added to the DOM correctly, but something is preventing the links from being selected.

This is how my tooltip looks after the cursor hovers over one of the points in the scatterplot:

```
<div id="tooltip_svg_01" style="opacity: 1; left: 532.874px; top: 168px;">
  <p><strong>Important Label Heading</strong></p>
  <p><span id="value_tt_01">0.11318094,79</span></p>
  <p><a id="link_tt_01" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2">0.11318094,79</a></p>
</div>
```

Is there some kind of event handling that is capturing the `click` on the url that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in the styles:

This line is the problem it does not allows mouse events.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Your code:

```
    #tooltip_svg_01 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none; //this line is the problem
    }
```

Working code:

```
    #tooltip_svg_01 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9u9a30y4/9/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Cyril. I had completely missed that.